# $_POST in php not having a value

Tags: php, post, apache2

I have created two php files. The first is encrypt.php which sends textareas to handleData.php. Currently this just saves the input to a text file but even that does not work. The text file stays as it was before and post seems to not have passed any data. I have also tried to echo the data explicitly but it remains blank. Why is post not sending any data? I have done everything right as far as I can see and name the textareas but it refuses to work

encrypt.php

```
<form method="POST" action="handleData.php">                                                                                                                                   
    <p><textarea name="plaintext" placeholder="Enter text to encrypt" rows="10" cols="50"><?php echo exec("cat input.txt")?></textarea></p>                                      
    <p><textarea name="ciphertext" placeholder="Enter text to decrypt" rows="10" cols="50"><?php echo exec("cat output.txt")?></textarea></p>                                    
    <p><input type="submit" value="Encrypt/Decrypt" onClick="location.reload()"></p>                                                                                             
</form>
```

handleData.php

```
<?php                                                                                                                                                                                
    $num = "3128342308234";                                                                                                                                                           

    $plain = (isset($_POST['plaintext'])) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['plaintext']) : 'test';                                                                                           
    $cipher = (isset($_POST['ciphertext'])) ? $_POST['ciphertext'] : '';                                                                                                              
    echo $_POST['plaintext'];                                                                                                                                                         
    exec("$plain >> input.txt");                                                                                                                                                      
    $command = "encryptPoly ".$num." ".$plain;                                                                                                                                        
    exec("rm output.txt");                                                                                                                                                            
    exec($command." >> output.txt");                                                                                                                                                  
?>
```

Comment: I tried to get this to work using PHP but I ended up using Python's web module which was able to accomplish this much easier. Thank you for you help though.

Answer (score 0):

you are reloading the page, therefore not submitting,

```
<p><input type="submit" value="Encrypt/Decrypt" onClick="location.reload()"></p>
```

simply remove the onClick:

```
<p><input type="submit" value="Encrypt/Decrypt"></p>
```

and make sure the action for this is the same name as the current file.

```
<form method="POST" action="handleData.php">
```

Comment: The issue is you are trying to send data to a separate page while reloading the current, try removing the onclick event.

Comment: I'm using the separate page to update text files which then are displayed in the original text files by the php code "exec("cat output.txt)". Would the onClick cause the POST to not send?

Comment: as i said in the answer `you are reloading the page, therefore not submitting`, by adding your own `onClick` event, you are removing the default action.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
<?php                                                                                                                                                                                
$num = "3128342308234";                                                                                                                                                           

$plain = (isset($_POST['plaintext'])) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['plaintext']) : 'test';                                                                                           
$cipher = (isset($_POST['ciphertext'])) ? $_POST['ciphertext'] : '';                                                                                                              
echo $_POST['plaintext'];                                                                                                                                                         
exec("$plain >> input.txt");                                                                                                                                                      
$command = "encryptPoly ".$num." ".$plain;                                                                                                                                        
exec("rm output.txt");                                                                                                                                                            
exec($command." >> output.txt");                                                                                                                                                  
?>
```

to:

```
<?php                                                                                                                                                                                
$num = "3128342308234";                                                                                                                                                           

$plain = (isset($_POST['plaintext'])) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['plaintext']) : 'test';                                                                                           
$cipher = (isset($_POST['ciphertext'])) ? $_POST['ciphertext'] : '';                                                                                                              
echo $_POST['plaintext'];                                                                                                                                                         
exec("$plain >> input.txt");                                                                                                                                                      
$command = "encryptPoly ".$num." ".$plain;                                                                                                                                        
exec("rm output.txt");                                                                                                                                                            
exec($command." >> output.txt");

header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);// Go back to previous page.  

?>
```

Comment: I tried this and it did nothing. Also removing the onClick just made the page not refresh now, POST still doesn't work